# Do not open Apple Music when pressing a media key

Tags: itunes, catalina, apple-music

How do I prevent Apple Music from opening when pressing a media key?

If I have Sonos or Spotify opened, the media keys control them as they should. If they are closed, annoyingly, Apple Music opens, prompts login etc. How do I make it disappear from my life completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This still works with Big Sur and above:

```
launchctl bootout "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
launchctl disable "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
```

The top command disables it immediately. The bottom command prevents it from reactivating on restart.

To return to the default behaviour, replace `bootout` with `bootstrap` and `disable` with `enable`:

```
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
launchctl enable "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
```

Note this may disable the media keys for other apps as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know it was possible to do without 3rd party software. This is great.

Comment: I'm running BigSur 11.4 on a M1 mac mini & get the following errors:
`Boot-out failed: 125: Unknown error: 125` and <br/>`Could not disable service: 125: Domain does not support specified action`

Comment: could you provide an example of this command.
it does not work for me:
>launchctl bootout "gui/$(id -u "$jonnyuser")/com.apple.rcd"
should it just be >launchctl bootout "gui/jonnyuser/com.apple.rcd"

could you also explain the parts of this command, because apple music is Music.app and it does not feature in your answer, it would be great to clarify.

Comment: >launchctl bootout gui/501/com.apple.rcd < works, but putting it back >launchctl bootstrap gui/501/com.apple.rcd < does not work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you do to achieve your requirements.

But you have to disable Apple’s SIP which I don't recommend personally.

So, I would suggest you use this third-party application named as [Mac Media Key Forwarder](http://milgra.com/mac-media-key-forwarder.html). Use the latest version 3.0 for Catalina.

> You can prioritize which app you would like to control or you can go
>   with the default behaviour which controls the running app. The app
>   runs in the menu bar.

Download the app and move it to your Applications folder. Double-click to start it and you will see a black dot appear in your taskbar. Click on the dot and make sure that the option to start on session initialization is ticked. Then change the option to give priority to Spotify over Apple Music for your media keys.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it without any CLI commands. I'm on macOS Monterey 12.5.

Go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard` and check `Enable Full Keyboard Access`.

[image]

After I did that, it stopped opening Apple Music and media keys started working with Spotify again.

**[UPDATE]**

Ended up disabling it since it was messing with my input, but the media controls are still working with Spotify. Since I can't reproduce it I'm not sure if enabling this once did the trick or if it's something else I did. So I'll leave this answer here for others to check if it works.