# launchctl: Unrecognized target specifier

Tags: bash, launchd

I think that at one point in the past I disabled my media keys using the instructions provided in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415478/408816). I am trying to re-enable them, but upon using the command:

```
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
```

I get the error:

```
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl bootstrap <domain-target> [service-path, service-path2, ...]
```

Because I'm a little confused about the "USER" part, I have also tried replacing `USER` with my username in different ways:

```
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "${matt}")/com.apple.rcd
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "matt")/com.apple.rcd
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u matt)/com.apple.rcd
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.rcd
```

All of these return the same error.

Answer (score 1):

To bootstrap you need to specify the path to the .plist file where the daemon is defined. For com.apple.rcd that's `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`.

Run the following:

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/$(id -u) /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist

launchctl enable gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.rcd
```