# What does `man launchctl` means?

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

I'm trying to run this line in the terminal.

```
launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
```

I'm not sure what does this means. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means in **Terminal** to execute `man launchctl` and read it _manual page_.

Comment: Why do you think you need to run that launchctl ine, since you don't know what it does?

Comment: @MarcWilson I followed [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380126/do-not-open-apple-music-when-pressing-a-media-key) to disable the media key of launching Apple Music. It worked, but later I wasn't able to revert it.

I think I fix it by manually editing the file `disabled.501.plist`

Answer (score 1):

`man` command refers to [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) which is a software documentation system available for command line applications and libraries available on Unix systems.

In your case, what the command output is advising you is to refer to the man page for the `launchctl` command by running the command:

`man launchctl`

The man page for a command or a library function, if installed on system, can be viewed by running the command:

`man <command_name>`

To search if `man` page for a command or a library function is installed on your system, run:

`man -aw <command_name>`

to view the path of installed man page(s).

Comment: Another way to open the command's `man` page, on a Mac, is to right-click on the command in the terminal and select `Open man Page` from the menu which pop up.