# How do you undo a "launchctl bootout" command to disable the media keys?

Tags: macos, launchd, sonoma

I tried out the set of commands listed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415478/513102) while setting up a new MacBook Pro on Sonoma 14.1.2.

The below command worked and disabled the media keys -

```
$ launchctl bootout "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
```

However the other command to enable them back again does not work for me -

```
$ launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(id -u "${USER}")/com.apple.rcd"
Usage: launchctl bootstrap <domain-target> [service-path, service-path2, ...
<service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
```

What does this error message mean? I'm hoping I can get the second command to work to re-enable the media play/pause keys.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to [@theKosh on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/masklinn/a532dfe55bdeab3d60ab8e46ccc38a68?permalink_comment_id=4023392#gistcomment-4023392) for more details on how to use `launchctl bootstrap`,

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/$UID /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

I think the `enable` part of the answer works for future logins, though. Simplified:

```
launchctl enable gui/$UID/com.apple.rcd
```